# Make perl exit with 1 if a string is found

Tags: bash, perl

I want a bash command (perl?) that will output a non-zero exit code if a non-ASCII character is found in a text file.

Here's what I have so far:

```
perl -nle 'print "$." if m/[\x80-\xFF]/' file_that_has_non_ascii_characters.txt
```

This prints out each line that a non-ASCII character is found on. I tried a variant with `exit 1` in it, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
➜ perl -nle 'exit 1 if m/[\x80-\xFF]/' file_that_has_non_ascii_characters.txt
➜ echo $!
0
```

How do I do this?

Comment: The exit code is in `$?` in `bash`.

Comment: Why aren't you looking at `$?`?

Comment: See [Exit and Exit Status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)

Comment: "*This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or **a simple typographical error.** While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `$?` instead of `$!`.

> `!`: Expands to the process ID of the most recently executed  background  (asynchronous) command.
>
> `?`: Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.